# How do I delete custom entity instances?

Tags: 8, entities

I've create a custom entity content with Drupal console,

```
 drupal generate:entity:content
```

Now I want delete (remove) it completely, how can I achieve it with drupal console or drush ?

my drupal version is **8.1.8** and my drupal console is 1.0 beta 5

**update**
I have serveral Entity in my module and I want to only remove one Content type, uninstalling module cause all Entity Database table dropped.

I know I can looking for entity table in database remove it and all related file manually **I looking for a method with Drupal console or Drush**

Comment: I don't think there is a delete command for entity types, you can manually delete the class file you have created using `drupal generate:entity:content`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Drush 9+ supports deleting custom entities
`drush entity:delete my_custom_entity`

Answer (score 3):

1. You can use  drush genc 0 —kill –types=article but you need to
   install devel_generate.
2. You can also install Drush Delete All module available for drupal 8 [module link](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_delete)

Comment: Thanks for you attention Dear, but this is not my question answer.

Comment: Those answers are for deleting entities. Post is about removing the entity TYPE. Which i am trying to sort out myself. I have removed every instance of it showing up in the code; but still my site WSOD saying the entity type doesnt exist.

Answer (score 2):

### Delete all *custom entities* of a type:

Using [Drupal Console](https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/content/en/commands/entity-delete.html) (best method):

```
drupal entity:delete custom_type --all
```

Download and install [Drush Delete All](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_delete) module and do:

```
drush delete-all-entity custom_type
```

which is the same as `drush dae custom_type`

### Delete all *nodes* of a type:

**Option 1:** Using [Drupal Console](https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/content/en/commands/entity-delete.html) (best method):

```
drupal entity:delete node --all
```

**Option 1:** Download devel module and install devel_generate submodule
You can then use drush (as per @shreya's answer) or the UI:

```
drush genc 0 —kill –types=article
```

**Option 2:** Download and install [Drush Delete All](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_delete) module and do:

```
drush delete-all article
```

Comment: Not what is being asked. See my comment above.

Comment: @liquidcms you realise this answer is from 2018! Perhaps you need to post a new question?