# Cannot disable module "monitoring" after failed upgrade

Tags: drush, updating, composer

I just updated to Drupal 8.8.1 (`composer update drupal/* --with-dependencies` now says I'm up to date, even though I know that 8.8.2 is actually the most recent).  After doing this, I can use most of the site fine, but when I went to update the monitoring module, I get the error `The geoip PHP extension is not installed!` which I cannot install because it is obsolete.  Now I believe the database is corrupt because the process would not complete the installation and when I try got to `https://.../admin/modules` I get the stack trace below.  I have tried using drush to remove the monitoring module but when I do I get:

```
In PmCommands.php line 129:

  monitoring: There is content for the entity type: Monitoring sensor result. <a href="/admin/modules/uninstall/entity/monitoring_sensor_result">Remove monitoring sensor
   result entities</a>.
```

Do I really need to disable all of the monitors to uninstall and reinstall everything?  Is there any way I can do it in one command?  And is this even the problem?  Thanks.

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Drupal\monitoring\Sensor\SensorManager::__construct(), 5 passed in /var/www/html/otherrealm.org/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php on line 285 and exactly 6 expected in Drupal\monitoring\Sensor\SensorManager->__construct() (line 73 of modules/monitoring/src/Sensor/SensorManager.php).

Drupal\monitoring\Sensor\SensorManager->__construct(Object, Object, Object, Object, Object) (Line: 285)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService(Array, 'monitoring.sensor_manager') (Line: 173)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('monitoring.sensor_manager') (Line: 52)
Drupal\monitoring\Plugin\rest\resource\MonitoringSensorConfigResource::create(Object, Array, 'monitoring-sensor', Array) (Line: 21)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\Factory\ContainerFactory->createInstance('monitoring-sensor', Array) (Line: 83)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\PluginManagerBase->createInstance('monitoring-sensor', Array) (Line: 62)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultSingleLazyPluginCollection->initializePlugin('monitoring-sensor') (Line: 80)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\LazyPluginCollection->get('monitoring-sensor') (Line: 83)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultSingleLazyPluginCollection->setConfiguration(Array) (Line: 99)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultSingleLazyPluginCollection->addInstanceId('monitoring-sensor', Array) (Line: 55)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultSingleLazyPluginCollection->__construct(Object, 'monitoring-sensor', Array) (Line: 213)
Drupal\rest\Entity\RestResourceConfig->getPluginCollections() (Line: 118)
Drupal\rest\Entity\RestResourceConfig->getResourcePlugin() (Line: 59)
Drupal\rest\RestPermissions->permissions()
call_user_func(Array) (Line: 149)
Drupal\user\PermissionHandler->buildPermissionsYaml() (Line: 108)
Drupal\user\PermissionHandler->getPermissions() (Line: 119)
Drupal\user\PermissionHandler->moduleProvidesPermissions('action') (Line: 248)
Drupal\system\Form\ModulesListForm->buildRow(Array, Object, 'Drupal') (Line: 174)
Drupal\system\Form\ModulesListForm->buildForm(Array, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 520)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->retrieveForm('system_modules', Object) (Line: 277)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm(Object, Object) (Line: 91)
Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult(Object, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 573)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 151)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
Drupal\ban\BanMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 694)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

Comment: If you don't care about those entities, you just want rid of the whole thing, you could try the solutions [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/255938/89581) for deleting entities with drush or drupal console?

Comment: That was really dumb of me ‍♂️! https://.../admin/modules/uninstall/entity/monitoring_sensor_result was a link to a page to uninstall them. (why I should have taken a break before I had posted this)

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar problem for the visitors module. But nothing I do can fix it, as I cannot get to any of the /admin pages. If I try /update.php, it stops with an error that geoip is required. This is all happening after reinstalled the whole large, production website from backup of public_html and backup of the database. I am baffled, does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Hi Lucas, Welcome to DSE, please create a new question with your problem. Do not post your question as answer to other questions. You can link this question in your new question.